# $lookup with two $concat fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

Given those documents:

```
{
    "name" : "User",
    "class" : "clazz",
    "reference" : "ref"
}

{
    "classReference" : "clazz+ref",
    "room" : "123"
}
```

How can I do a $lookup to retrieve a document like this (without changing the documents):

```
{
    "name" : "User",
    "class" : "clazz",
    "reference" : "ref",
    "classReference" : "clazz+ref",
    "room" : "123"
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `classReference`? "clazz" or "ref" ?

Comment: Both concatenated (poor symbol choice). Edited the question to better reflect my desire.

Comment: So which is the referenced(common) field in the documents?

Comment: the field classReference is the concatenation of both class and reference of the first document. In SQL I would get something like `SELECT * FROM user, room WHERE room.classReference = CONCAT(user.name, user.class)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Room.collection.name,
    "let": { "ref": { "$concat": ["$class", "$reference"] } },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$classReference", "$$ref"] } } }
    ],
    "as": "ref"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "classReference": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ref.classReference", 0] },
    "room": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ref.room", 0] },
    "name": 1,
    "class": 1
    "reference": 1
  }}
])
```

Basically you need to  [**`$concat`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) both the `class` and `reference` and then pass it to [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline.